ATSAME70 outputting clock on xin/xout and operating without crystal
I need to operate an ATSAME70 on an external 16MHz crystal. I had the crystal soldered onto the PCB and tried to enable it in MCC Harmony. For some reason the entire CPU started operating at a fraction of the desired frequency, meaning UART ran on half the Baud-Rate specified, an LED that was supposed to flash once every second started flashing once every 5 seconds. I used an oscilloscope to verify that the crystal is providing the correct 16MHz clock signal, and it looks alright. I tried shorting the crystal to GND next to see if the CPU would stop operating, but it didn't. I went ahead and desoldered the crystal, and much to my surprise it was still operating, and whats even more surprising, it does output a clock signal on XIN and XOUT. Connecting a crystal, even a 4MHz crystal, does not change the frequency on XIN and XOUT.
Why is the CPU behaving this way and how can I make sure it does run from the external clock? What is a reason for the CPU to apparently drive the pins strong enough so the crystal can't even operate?

From the datasheet, the default clock at reset is the is the internal clock with 12MHz selected.
The first task of an programmer is to set up the clock tree to the desired values. The data sheet gives you this information.



I did that using MCC Harmony. When I run from the internal clock it runs at the frequency specified, only when running from the external clock it outputs a clock on XIN and XOUT and connecting a crystal does not affect the frequency of that clock signal.

@Wiers The  Main Crystal Oscillator Failure Detection section of the datasheet contains If a failure of Main crystal oscillator is detected, PMC_SR.CFDEV and PMC_SR.FOS both indicate a failure event.. As an initial debugging step suggest to monitor the PMC_SR.CFDEV and PMC_SR.FOS flags to see if the Main Crystal Oscillator has been marked as failed.
